# TextField Validation hooked to JSON

Tags: swiftui

I'm struggling to find a logical approach to validate the TextField. I have successffuly managed to decode JSON and display however i want to let users type in an answer and then compare that to all of the possible "answers" from the JSON for that particular question and maybe add a green chevron if it’s validated.

I managed to hook the TextField to the "question" as well but how i'll capture the user input and compare with the "answer" section? I'm aware of the .onSubmit and .onAppear modifiers but i don't know how to do it.

Any advice, thank you

```
// CONTENT VIEW 

    import SwiftUI
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        var item: [Exercises] = Bundle.main.decode("random.json")
        @State private var items1: [Exercises] = []
        @State private var isMatched = false
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationStack {
                List($items1) { $item in
                    Text(item.question)
                    TextField("Tap to create", text: $item.text)
                        .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                        .autocorrectionDisabled()
                        
                }
                .navigationTitle("Variables")
            }
                
                Button(action: {
                  addItem()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Button")
                })
            }
        
        private func addItem() {
            guard let newItem = item.randomElement() else {return}
            withAnimation {
                items1.insert(newItem, at: 0)
            }
        }
        
    }
     
    #Preview {
        ContentView()
    }



// MODEL 

    import Foundation
    
    
    struct Exercises: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
        let id: Int
        let question: String
        var answer: [String]
        var text: String
    }
    
    
        extension Bundle {
            func decode<T: Codable>(_ file: String) -> T {
                guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
                    fatalError("Could not find \(file) in bundle.")
                }
                
                guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
                    fatalError("Could not load \(file) from bundle.")
                }
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                
                guard let loadedData = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
                    fatalError("Could not decode \(file) from bundle.")
                }
                
                return loadedData
            }
        }


// JSON 

    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "question": "Create a variable called \"greeting\" and assign the value: Hello",
            "answer": ["var greeting = \"Hello\"","var greeting = \"hello\""],
            "text": ""
        },
        
        {
            "id": 2,
            "question": "Create a variable called \"person\" and assign the value: John",
            "answer": ["var person = \"John\"","var person = \"john\""],
            "text": ""
        },
        
        {
            "id": 3,
            "question": "Create a variable called \"city\" and assign the value: London",
            "answer": ["var city = \"London\"","var city = \"london\""],
            "text": ""
        },
        
        {
            "id": 4,
            "question": "Create a variable called \"food\" and assign the value: kebab",
            "answer": ["var food = \"Kebab\"","var food = \"kebab\""],
            "text": ""
        },
        
        {
            "id": 5,
            "question": "Create a variable called \"country\" and assign the value: United Kingdom",
            "answer": ["var country = \"United Kingdom\"","var country = \"united kingdom\""],
            "text": ""
        },
        
        {
            "id": 6,
            "question": "Create a constant called \"car\" and assign the value: orange",
            "answer": ["let car = \"orange\"","let car = \"Orange\""],
            "text": ""
        },
        
        {
            "id": 7,
            "question": "Create a constant called \"laptop\" and assign the value: MacBook",
            "answer": ["let laptop = \"macbook\"","let laptop = \"Macbook\""],
            "text": ""
        },
        
        {
            "id": 8,
            "question": "Create a constant called \"planet\" and assign the value: Mars",
            "answer": ["let planet = \"mars\"","let planet = \"Mars\""],
            "text": ""
        },
        
        {
            "id": 9,
            "question": "Create a constant called \"type\" and assign the value: electric",
            "answer": ["let type = \"electric\"","let type = \"Electric\""],
            "text": ""
        },
        
        {
            "id": 10,
            "question": "Create a constant called \"color\" and assign the value: green",
            "answer": ["let color = \"green\"","let color = \"Green\""],
            "text": ""
        },
        
        {
            "id": 11,
            "question": "Create a variable of type int called \"house\" and assign the value: 5",
            "answer": ["var house = 5"],
            "text": ""
        },
        
        {
            "id": 12,
            "question": "Create a variable of type int called \"doors\" and assign the value: 2",
            "answer": ["var doors: Int = 2"],
            "text": ""
        },
        
        {
            "id": 13,
            "question": "Create a constant of type int called \"windows\" and assign the value: 10",
            "answer": ["let windows: Int = 10"],
            "text": ""
        },
        
        {
            "id": 14,
            "question": "Create a constant of type int called \"wheels\" and assign the value: 4",
            "answer": ["let wheels: Int = 4"],
            "text": ""
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach using your original code with `.onSubmit` (for testing) and a small
function in the `Exercise` model.

Note I changed some of the names to better reflect the
meaning of the property, eg with or without `s`

The `func isCorrectAnswer()` removes any white spaces from the text and
also removes the `\"` from the answers for the comparison.

In the example code, the TextField border turns green if it is the correct answer.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var items: [Exercise] = Bundle.main.decode("random.json")
    @State private var items1: [Exercise] = []
    @State private var isMatched = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List($items1) { $item in
                Text(item.question)
                TextField("Tap to create", text: $item.text)
                    .border(item.isCorrectAnswer() ? .green : .red) // <-- for testing
                    .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                    .autocorrectionDisabled()
                    // -- for testing
                    .onSubmit {
                        let isCorrectAnswer = item.isCorrectAnswer()
                        print("-----> isCorrectAnswer: \(isCorrectAnswer) ")
                    }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Variables")
        }
        
        Button(action: {
            addItem()
        }, label: {
            Text("Button")
        })
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        guard let newItem = items.randomElement() else {return}
        withAnimation {
            items1.insert(newItem, at: 0)
        }
    }
    
}

struct Exercise: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable { // <--- here
    let id: Int
    let question: String
    var answer: [String]  
    var text: String
    
    // --- here
    func isCorrectAnswer() -> Bool {
       answer.contains(where: {
        $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "") == text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        })
     }
 }
```